# C programing , to generate a float between two whole numbers

Tags: c

C programming
I want to generate a float number (money ex 32.52) from a range of 10 to 40, inclusive.

```
float money;
srand(time(NULL));
money = 10+ ( rand() % (40 - 10 + 1 ));
printf("Show amount: %.2f ",money);
```

This only generates whole numbers (ex: 17.00 ; 20.00.....)

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408990/how-to-generate-random-float-number-in-c

Comment: What about generating a random number between 100 and 400 and dividing it by 10.0f? You also can adjust the limit values to get every precision you want.

Comment: As a small aside, if you're generating production software, you should definitely not use a 'float' to store your monetary values, as the precision of a float is too small. There's already a discussion on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency That being said, if it's just a formative question, feel free to disregard. The other answers are all valid in showing you how to get a float out of your integer calculation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
money = 10 + (float)rand()/RAND_MAX * (40 - 10);
```

Comment: This formula cannot generate `40.0` exactly. Thus the range `10` to `40` is not inclusive.

Comment: RAND_MAX is the maximum value returned from rand(). 10 + RAND_MAX/RAND_MAX * (40 - 10) = 40

Comment: Right, I mean it can generate 40.0 exactly.

Comment: @JamesT.Huggett; No. It can't.

Comment: My bad, yes it can generate `40.0` exactly... but all the other shortcomings related to the use of `double` or worse `floats` remain.

Comment: @JamesT.Huggett; Read some tutorials about floating point comparison. Do you think `(float)rand()/RAND_MAX ` will ever produce `1.0`?

Comment: Actually, there might be cases where this formula will not generate `40.0` exactly: `RAND_MAX` may have a value that cannot be represented exactly as a `float`.  For example `INT32_MAX` cannot be converted exactly as a 32 bit `float`.  `(float)RAND_MAX/RAND_MAX` will be `1.0` if it is evaluated as `(float)RAND_MAX/(float)RAND_MAX`, but might not if it is evaluated as `(float)RAND_MAX/(double)RAND_MAX`.

Comment: The C11 Standard sates in section 6.3.1.8 that: *Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `float`.*  It should be safe to assume that `(float)RAND_MAX/RAND_MAX` must be evaluated as `(float)RAND_MAX/(float)RAND_MAX` but for some reason, I feel uncomfortable relying on this.

Comment: @haccks: never say never! `(float)rand()/RAND_MAX` may rarely produce `1.0` exactly, especially if `RAND_MAX` is large, but what makes you think it should never do it?

Comment: Look at this link http://ideone.com/JlNAl1
It does produce 1.0. I don't know what you guys are going on about.

Comment: When rand() returns RAND_MAX then rand()/RAND_MAX == 1. Even if those numbers are rounded in some way. There is nothing else it could equal.

Answer (score 0):

The `rand()` function generates pseudo-random integers with values between `0` and `RAND_MAX` inclusive.  Your formula involves integer operations thus produces integer values.  Your goal can be achieved this way:

```
double money;

money = 10.0 + (double)rand() * 30.0 / (double)RAND_MAX;
printf("Show amount: %.2f ", money);
```

This will generate peudo-random floating point values in the target range.  It may not fit your purpose because these values will not a be a round number of cents.  Indeed IEEE floats or doubles cannot precisely represent all exact numbers of cents.  You will come closer by using this method:

```
money = 10.0 + (double)(rand() % 3001) / 100.0;
```

values will be as close as possible to exact numbers of cents, but a more accurate and simpler method is just to compute with integer amounts of cents and convert to currency only at print time:

```
int money = 1000 + rand() % (4000 - 1000 + 1);

printf("Show amount: %d.02d", money / 100, money % 100);
```

If `money` can be negative, extra care must be taken to print negative values:

```
if (money < 0) {
    printf("Show amount: -%u.02u", -money / 100, -money % 100);
} else {
    printf("Show amount: %d.02d", money / 100, money % 100);
}
```

If you decide to use floating point values, use the `double` type.
Some casts in the above examples are not strictly necessary as promotion rules will make them implicit, I wrote them on purpose for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Between `[10.00 ... 40.00]` there are `(40.00-10.00)*100 + 1` `0.01` numbers.

```
srand(time(NULL));
#define NUM_COUNT (4000-1000 + 1)
float money = 10.0 + (rand()%NUM_COUNT)/100.0;
printf("Show amount: %.2f ",money);
```

Recommend using `double` vs. `float`. [@Matt Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407051/c-programing-to-generate-a-float-between-two-whole-numbers/32899732#comment46989365_29407051)