# How to generate random floating point numbers from 0 to 1

Tags: c, random

I have found a code in this answer [How to generate a random integer number from within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range?answertab=active#tab-top) a code that works perfectly, but tis is for integers. Does anybody know how can I change this code so it returns uniformly a number between 0 and 1?

```
#include <stdlib.h> // For random(), RAND_MAX
// Assumes 0 <= max <= RAND_MAX
// Returns in the closed interval [0, max]
long random_at_most(long max) {
  unsigned long
  // max <= RAND_MAX < ULONG_MAX, so this is okay.
  num_bins = (unsigned long) max + 1,
  num_rand = (unsigned long) RAND_MAX + 1,
  bin_size = num_rand / num_bins,
  defect   = num_rand % num_bins;

  long x;
  do {
    x = random();
  }
  // This is carefully written not to overflow
  while (num_rand - defect <= (unsigned long)x);

  // Truncated division is intentional
  return x/bin_size;
}
```

Comment: try randomizing from 0-100 (Integer) then just divide 1 by the answer. Ex: return 1/(randomizeNum)

Comment: What do you mean? Do you wish to rewrite this to use floating point? If so please post your attempts of doing that. If not, then this question makes no sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409133/2630032

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408990/how-to-generate-random-float-number-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need all that complicated code there. Imagining you initialized your pseudo-random number generator correctly in your main function, with for instance something like this for [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/):

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

The following code should be enough:

```
double random(){

    return (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
}
```

The idea there is just to pick a random number between 0 and RAND_MAX, and then to divide it by RAND_MAX. As RAND_MAX/RAND_MAX is equal to 1, you will return a random value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

The C way:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        printf("Random value: %f\n", (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX);
        return 0;
    }
```

The C++11 way:

```
    #include <random>

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        std::default_random_engine generator;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(0.0, 1.0);

        printf("Random value: %f\n", distribution(generator));

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The question is for C, not C++.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just missed the tag. The answer also contains the rand() solution, so will work for C too :)

Comment: The problem is that I want many of them, about 150000 so the programme must returns numbers uniformly

Comment: To be edited (I can't): correct type conversion for "the C way" goes like this: `(float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX`