# What is the safe way to generate random number with a known seed using OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, random, parallel-processing, openmp

I am looking for a way to be able to safely generate random numbers in parallel with OpenMP while the input seed is already known. I searched and ended up with OMPRNG. Is there another way  expect using a package that I can manually write a code?
Also, I would like to mention that I need these random numbers for monto Carlo integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of the monte Carlo Simulation you can use [rand_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r). From this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287531/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-parallel/4288024#4288024) one can read:

> I think you're looking for rand_r(), which explicitly takes the
> current RNG state as a parameter. Then each thread should have it's
> own copy of seed data (whether you want each thread to start off with
> the same seed or different ones depends on what you're doing, here you
> want them to be different or you'd get the same row again and again).

This is actually the function used on the parallel implementation of a Monte Carlo Simulation in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561372/1366871) that actually yield good results. The code from that answer:

```
int main(void)
{
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    long points = 1000000000; //....................................... INPUT AVOIDED
    long m = 0;
    unsigned long HAUSNUMERO = 1;
    double DIV1byMAXbyMAX = 1. / RAND_MAX / RAND_MAX;

    int threads = get_nprocs();
    omp_set_num_threads(threads);
    #pragma omp parallel reduction (+: m )
    {
        unsigned int aThreadSpecificSEED_x = HAUSNUMERO + 1 + omp_get_thread_num();
        unsigned int aThreadSpecificSEED_y = HAUSNUMERO - 1 + omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for(long i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            double x = rand_r( &aThreadSpecificSEED_x );
            double y = rand_r( &aThreadSpecificSEED_y );
            m += (1  >= ( x * x + y * y ) * DIV1byMAXbyMAX);
        }
    }
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("%f\n",end-start);
    printf("Pi is roughly %lf\n", (double) 4*m / (double) points);
}
```

Quoting from the comment section ([Sam Manson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358308/sam-mason)):

> Might be worth noting that rand_r only has an int for state (i.e.
> likely 32bits), so the entire space could get exhausted pretty quickly
> during a large MC run. 128 bits of state seems more reasonable, which
> would necessitate some other algorithm (e.g. PCG-64 or xoroshiro128)

Answer (score 1):

Just start with an initial seed, compute seeds for each thread and use a good RNG with that thread-specific seed.

For a good RNG you might want to read about [PCG](https://www.pcg-random.org/) .

Comment: the generators in PCG are generally not safe for this use, even if you try to randomize the seed in each thread.