# How to get the correct order of execution of pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, histogram

I was doing Histogram using pthreads and after long struggle on it.. finally it said:

```
Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)
```

unfortunately I had this line

```
p=(struct1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct1));
```

after getting the values to the struct variables from command line.. So that was cleared off.. Thanks for @DNT for letting me know that..

Now when I try to execute the following program.. It sometimes displays the output and sometimes it is going out to the `which_bin` function and prints the following

```
output type 1(which is not the correct output): 
Data = 0.000000 doesn't belong to a bin! 
Quitting

output type 2(almost the correct output of histo with time taken by threads): 
10.000-28.000: 
28.000-46.000: 
46.000-64.000: 
64.000-82.000: 
82.000-100.000: XXXXXXXXXX 
The code to be timed took 0.000415 seconds
```

My ques is why the same prog when ran shows different outputs.. I am confused of what it is exactly looking for..

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include "timer.h"
    void Usage(char prog_name[]);

    void Gen_data(void *p);
    void Gen_bins(void *p);
    int Which_bin(void *p);
    void Print_histo(void *p);


    void func(void *p);

    struct test
    {
     int bin_count, i, bin;
     float min_meas, max_meas;
     float* bin_maxes;
     int* bin_counts;
     int data_count;
     float* data;
    };

    typedef struct test struct1;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    double start, finish, elapsed;
    GET_TIME(start);

    struct1 *p;
    pthread_t th1, th2, th3;

    p=(struct1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct1));
    if (argc != 5)
        Usage(argv[0]);
    p->bin_count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    p->min_meas = strtof(argv[2], NULL);
    p->max_meas = strtof(argv[3], NULL);
    p->data_count = strtol(argv[4], NULL, 10);

    p->bin_maxes = malloc(p->bin_count*sizeof(float));
    p->bin_counts = malloc(p->bin_count*sizeof(int));
    p->data = malloc(p->data_count*sizeof(float));


    pthread_create(&th1,NULL,(void*) Gen_data,(void*) p);
    pthread_create(&th2,NULL,(void*) Gen_bins,(void*) p);
    pthread_create(&th3,NULL,(void*) func,(void*) p);
    printf("Hi\n");


    pthread_join(th1,NULL);
    pthread_join(th2,NULL);
    pthread_join(th3,NULL);


    Print_histo(p);
    free(p->data);
    free(p->bin_maxes);
    free(p->bin_counts);

    GET_TIME(finish);
    elapsed = finish - start;
    printf("The code to be timed took %f seconds\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}  /* main */

void func(void *p)
{
    int i;
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;

    for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
    {
        args->bin = Which_bin(args);
        args->bin_counts[args->bin]++;
    }

    #  ifdef DEBUG
        printf("bin_counts = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
            printf("%d ", args->bin_counts[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #  endif
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:  Usage
 * Purpose:   Print a message showing how to run program and quit
 * In arg:    prog_name:  the name of the program from the command line
 */
void Usage(char prog_name[] /* in */)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s ", prog_name);
    fprintf(stderr, "<bin_count> <min_meas> <max_meas> <data_count>\n");
    exit(0);
}  /* Usage */


void Gen_data(void *p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int i;
    srandom(0);
    for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
        args->data[i] = args->min_meas + (args->max_meas - args->min_meas)*random()/((double) RAND_MAX);

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("data = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
            printf("%4.3f ", args->data[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #endif
} /* Gen_data */


void Gen_bins(void* p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    float bin_width;
    int   i;
    bin_width = (args->max_meas - args->min_meas)/args->bin_count;

    for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
    {
        args->bin_maxes[i] = args->min_meas + (i+1)*bin_width;
        args->bin_counts[i] = 0;
    }

    #  ifdef DEBUG
        printf("bin_maxes = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
            printf("%4.3f ", args->bin_maxes[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #  endif
}

int Which_bin(void* p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int bottom = 0, top =  args->bin_count-1;
    int mid;
    float bin_max, bin_min;

    while (bottom <= top)
    {
        mid = (bottom + top)/2;
        bin_max = args->bin_maxes[mid];
        bin_min = (mid == 0) ? args->min_meas: args->bin_maxes[mid-1];
        if (*(args->data) >= bin_max)
            bottom = mid+1;
        else if (*(args->data) < bin_min)
            top = mid-1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Data = %f doesn't belong to a bin!\n", args->data);
    fprintf(stderr, "Quitting\n");
    exit(-1);
}

void Print_histo(void *p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int i, j;
    float bin_max, bin_min;

    for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
    {
        bin_max = args->bin_maxes[i];
        bin_min = (i == 0) ? args->min_meas: args->bin_maxes[i-1];
        printf("%.3f-%.3f:\t", bin_min, bin_max);
        for (j = 0; j < args->bin_counts[i]; j++)
            printf("X");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Print_histo */    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "timer.h"
void Usage(char prog_name[]);

void Gen_data(void *p);
void Gen_bins(void *p);
int Which_bin(void *p);
void Print_histo(void *p);

void func(void *p);

pthread_mutex_t lock;
struct test
{
    int bin_count, i, bin;
    float min_meas, max_meas;
    float* bin_maxes;
    int* bin_counts;
    int data_count;
    float* data;
};

typedef struct test struct1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    double start, finish, elapsed;
    GET_TIME(start);

    struct1 *p;
    pthread_t th1, th2, th3;

    p=(struct1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct1));
    if (argc != 5)
        Usage(argv[0]);
    p->bin_count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    p->min_meas = strtof(argv[2], NULL);
    p->max_meas = strtof(argv[3], NULL);
    p->data_count = strtol(argv[4], NULL, 10);

    p->bin_maxes = malloc(p->bin_count*sizeof(float));
    p->bin_counts = malloc(p->bin_count*sizeof(int));
    p->data = malloc(p->data_count*sizeof(float));


    pthread_create(&th1,NULL,(void*) Gen_data,(void*) p);
    pthread_create(&th2,NULL,(void*) Gen_bins,(void*) p);
    pthread_create(&th3,NULL,(void*) func,(void*) p);
    printf("Hi\n");


    pthread_join(th1,NULL);
    pthread_join(th2,NULL);
    pthread_join(th3,NULL);


    Print_histo(p);
    free(p->data);
    free(p->bin_maxes);
    free(p->bin_counts);

    GET_TIME(finish);
    elapsed = finish - start;
    printf("The code to be timed took %f seconds\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}  /* main */

void func(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("th3 from Gen_func\n");
    int i;
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;

    for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
    {
        args->bin = Which_bin(args);
        args->bin_counts[args->bin]++;
    }

    #  ifdef DEBUG
        printf("bin_counts = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
            printf("%d ", args->bin_counts[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #  endif
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:  Usage
 * Purpose:   Print a message showing how to run program and quit
 * In arg:    prog_name:  the name of the program from the command line
 */
void Usage(char prog_name[] /* in */)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s ", prog_name);
    fprintf(stderr, "<bin_count> <min_meas> <max_meas> <data_count>\n");
    exit(0);
}  /* Usage */


void Gen_data(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("th1 from Gen_data\n");
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int i;
    srandom(0);
    for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
        args->data[i] = args->min_meas + (args->max_meas - args->min_meas)*random()/((double) RAND_MAX);

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("data = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
            printf("%4.3f ", args->data[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #endif
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
} /* Gen_data */


void Gen_bins(void* p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("th2 from Gen_bins\n");
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    float bin_width;
    int   i;
    bin_width = (args->max_meas - args->min_meas)/args->bin_count;

    for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
    {
        args->bin_maxes[i] = args->min_meas + (i+1)*bin_width;
        args->bin_counts[i] = 0;
    }

    #  ifdef DEBUG
        printf("bin_maxes = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
            printf("%4.3f ", args->bin_maxes[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #  endif
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int Which_bin(void* p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int bottom = 0, top =  args->bin_count-1;
    int mid;
    float bin_max, bin_min;

    while (bottom <= top)
    {
        mid = (bottom + top)/2;
        bin_max = args->bin_maxes[mid];
        bin_min = (mid == 0) ? args->min_meas: args->bin_maxes[mid-1];
        if (*(args->data) >= bin_max)
            bottom = mid+1;
        else if (*(args->data) < bin_min)
            top = mid-1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Data = %f doesn't belong to a bin!\n", args->data);
    fprintf(stderr, "Quitting\n");
    exit(-1);
}

void Print_histo(void *p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int i, j;
    float bin_max, bin_min;

    for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
    {
        bin_max = args->bin_maxes[i];
        bin_min = (i == 0) ? args->min_meas: args->bin_maxes[i-1];
        printf("%.3f-%.3f:\t", bin_min, bin_max);
        for (j = 0; j < args->bin_counts[i]; j++)
            printf("X");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Print_histo */
```

I have added the lines to see if all the threads are accessing its functions.. I observed this..

```
output 1:
Hi
th1 from Gen_data
th3 from Gen_func
Data = 0.000000 doesn't belong to a bin!
Quitting
```

In the output 1, I can see that th2 is not executed and program ended displaying error..

```
output 2:
th1 from Gen_data
Hi
th2 from Gen_bins
th3 from Gen_func
10.000-28.000:
28.000-46.000:
46.000-64.000:
64.000-82.000:
82.000-100.000: XXXXXXXXXX
The code to be timed took 0.000348 seconds
```

In output 2, all the threads are executed and so is the output..

I am confused that why the thread th2 is not being executed and how can I make sure that all threads runs in correct order..

I would like to know if the program is logically wrong? if it is wrong logically in that case why is it showing the histogram output at times.. Thanks!

Comment: Put your question in the title, not your google search.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the title.. My program is not in the correct order of execution of pthreads and how can i make sure threads execution? can it be done through mutex_lock/unlock..

Comment: And just to help with a future issue, since you seed your random number generator with 0, you get the same values back every run.  Seed it with time, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of thread execution is not guaranteed.  On a modern, multi-core processor, the threads may even execute concurrently.  There is no guarantee that the `Gen_bins` thread completes before the `func` thread.  Since your threads access and manipulate the same data structures, the results are unpredictable as you have noticed.

While I don't think threads are necessary for this application, make the following change to ensure the threads execute in the order listed.  Change:

```
pthread_create(&th1,NULL,(void*) Gen_data,(void*) p);
pthread_create(&th2,NULL,(void*) Gen_bins,(void*) p);
pthread_create(&th3,NULL,(void*) func,(void*) p);
pthread_join(th1,NULL);
pthread_join(th2,NULL);
pthread_join(th3,NULL);
```

to:

```
pthread_create(&th1,NULL,(void*) Gen_data,(void*) p);
pthread_join(th1,NULL);
pthread_create(&th2,NULL,(void*) Gen_bins,(void*) p);
pthread_join(th2,NULL);
pthread_create(&th3,NULL,(void*) func,(void*) p);
pthread_join(th3,NULL);
```

This ensures that each thread executes and completes before the next starts.  Again, since the threads aren't executing concurrently, threading isn't necessary for this program and just adds complexity.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to make the threads work concurrently so as to see performance in time when compared to serial execution.. How to make sure it works concurrently.. any idea would be of great help :)

Comment: You would need to add some synchronization constructs (locks/semaphores/conditionals).  Looking at your threads, `Gen_data`, `Gen_bins`, and `func`, neither `Gen_data` nor `Gen_bins` has any dependencies. `func`, however, can't run until `Gen_bins` complete (can't count till you have your bins, a conditional is one option for synchronization here) and it can't sort past the number of data items generated by `Gen_data` (a counting semaphore would be an option for synchronization here).

Comment: well.. thanks.. I will look forward to implement the conditional wait.. will that make sure that it works concurrently?

Comment: Yes, if coded correctly, but threads and synchronization can be tricky!  That is one possible solution, there are others.

Comment: What are the other ways which you mean other than sync!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science) for an overview of different synchronization methods.