# Selecting 1 no. from a given set randomly

Tags: c

if i want to select a particular no. like if from 1-100 randomly i want to select 1 no. . Is there any way .pleae help in sending the coding i am not from computer background. i'll be thankful to you in advance

```
- (int)randomNumber
{
int arr[100];
return arr[rand()%100];
}
```

Comment: You should've Googled first, you would've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c

Comment: What is the problem with the current code, you should first initialise  the array element

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int c, n;

        printf("Generate a  random numbers in between [1,100]\n");
        srand(time(NULL));
        n = rand()%100 + 1;
        printf("%d\n", n);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code will generate just one number, not ten as claimed in the printed message.

Answer (score 0):

i made a small program and here is the code snippet , i hope it helps.

```
 randomize(); // random number generation
 v1=random(100);
 delay(2000);
 printf("\n Computer chose ");
 printf("%d",v1);
```