# generating random numbers and checking for number of prime numbers

Tags: c

I want to create a program that generates random numbers and then asks a user to enter number of prime numbers that have been generated. If the number is correct, the user is declared winner, else, loses. Please help.

Comment: "Please help" with what? What's your question?

Comment: I think the question is "can you please do my home work?"

Comment: OK, thank you to share your wishes. What's your question? A question to be on-topic on SO must describe a specific problem, what you tried to solve it and where you stopped. _"These are my requirements, what to do?"_ questions are off-topic. I'd also suggest to read FAQ before asking.

Comment: Was simply asking for a C code

Comment: Propose a code with a problem and we can help you fixing it. But nobody's going to do the work for you from scratch...

Comment: @user3501133: Check out for random number :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c . Since the prime numbers are probably reasonably small I would just brute force if they are prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[10], i, j, n, count=0;
    srand(getpid()); //Every time it will give the different seed to rand(), so you wont get same array again and again
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = (rand()%100) + 1;

    printf("Enter the No of prime numbers!\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < arr[i]; j++)
            if (arr[i]%j == 0)
                break;
        if (arr[i] == j)
            count++;
    }
    printf("Prime Num in Array = %d, User I/p = %d\n",count,n);
    if(count == n)
        printf("Yeah! You have guessed correctly!\n");
    else
        printf("Sorry! Try again!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output-

```
root@ubuntu:~/c/basics# ./a.out 
Enter the No of prime numbers!
3
Prime Num in Array = 1, User I/p = 3
Sorry! Try again!
root@ubuntu:~/c/basics# ./a.out 
Enter the No of prime numbers!
2
Prime Num in Array = 2, User I/p = 2
Yeah! You have guessed correctly!
```

Comment: You code is bad. For example function main shall have return type int or getpid is not a standard C function. So its declaration can be absent in the used headers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i have modified that!

Comment: Indentation is bad too....

Answer (score 3):

Use standard C functions `srand` and `rand` declared in header `<stdlib.h>` to generate random numbers. Then write a function that determinates whether a given number is a prime number. Take into account that 1 is not a prime number. You can find yourself many examples of such functions here at stackoverflow.

Good luck!:)