# C generate 100 random numbers

Tags: c

In C I need to generate 100 random numbers and then sort them in descending order. As of now, I have this, and it is an absolute mess. I can tell I am going about it all wrong but am not experienced enough to actually be able to write this in a sane manner. Can anyone help?

```
/*100 random numbers in range 1-10*/
/*sorted in descending order*/
#include <stdio.h>
void random(char *nums, int count);

int main(void) {
    int random_num, count;
    char nums[100];
    for(count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        random(&nums, count);
    }

    for(count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        printf("%d\t", nums[count]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void random(char *nums, int count) {
    int random_data = fopen("/dev/random", "r");
    nums[count] = fread[random_data];
}
```

Comment: `fread[random_data];`?

Comment: You really need to learn more about the [input/output system in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c

Comment: You should also post your compiler errors and warnings.

Comment: Any why use the platform dependent random device instead of the [standard C `rand` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand)?

Comment: And if you do want to use the system's random device, use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`.

Comment: If this code is actually working for you and you just want it to work *better*, [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is an excellent resource. If not, you should always post error messages with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, call `rand()` on `stdlib.h`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int random_num, count;

    srand(time(NULL));
    char nums[100];
    for(count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        nums[count] = rand();
    }

    for(count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        printf("%d\t", nums[count]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now all I have to do is sort them, I guess. Is it possible to seed `/dev/random`?

Comment: Did you mean you'll use `/dev/random` for seed number of `srand()`?. It's possible if you convert it to `int` type.

Comment: Yes. It seems like `/dev/random` would definitely be a better choice anyways.

I got the random numbers down thanks to you, now to sort them.

Comment: @user3897320 `/dev/random` might be better. but how about microsecond. it could be obtained by `gettimeofday()`. and enjoy your sort ;)

Comment: Yeah, sorting is getting a little confusing but I don't want to ask for help.

It seems so easy, but somehow it just isn't. I've done it before, but can't remember how.

Answer (score 0):

1 random number: first srand(time(0)), then using rand() to generate the number you want

2 sort: using qsort(array, n, sizeof(int), comp);

```
 //here comp let the number in desc order
int  comp(const void*a,const void*b)
{
    return *(int*)b-*(int*)a;
}
```

both of  them need < stdlib.h>

Comment: I just made a for loop that I _think_ is quicksort. Your use of multiple pointers really throws me off. I desperately need to understand pointers and learn some damn algorithms!

Comment: The qsort function implements a quick-sort algorithm to sort an array of num elements, each of width bytes. The argument base is a pointer to the base of the array to be sorted. qsort overwrites this array with the sorted elements. The argument compare is a pointer to a user-supplied routine that compares two array elements and returns a value specifying their relationship. qsort calls the compare routine one or more times during the sort, passing pointers to two array elements on each call:

cmp((void*) & elem1, (void*)& elem2 );
you need to import int pointer.
PS: pointer is important

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I have also included code for sorting the values in descending order.

```
/*100 random numbers in range 1-10*/
/*Sorted in descending order*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void sorting(char *numbers) /* Sorting in descending order */
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=1;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100-i;j++)
        {
            if(numbers[j] < numbers[j+1])
            {
                temp = numbers[j+1];       
                numbers[j+1] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int random_num, count;

    srand(time(NULL));
    char nums[100];
    for(count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        /* Mod by 11 as we need range 1-10 */
        nums[count] = rand() % 11;
    }
    /* Sorting in descending order */
    sorting(nums);

    printf("Printing values after sorting.\n");
    for(count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```