# How to generate a real random number in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to generate a random probability with maximum of given probability. How could we generate a random real value between 0 and 0.5 in C?

Comment: I would suggest to write code the generates a value between 0 and 1, then refine it to limit to 0.5.

Comment: Here is a nice video about this issue : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: With just C? You can't. The best thing you could do is read a truly random value from a entropy source that gets fed with entropy from the physical world.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Comment: There are infinitely-many real numbers from 0 to 0.5, each with a probability of 0% of being chosen by your hypothetical random number generator. To try to salvage this question, I will ask you: to how many decimal places do you want to generate these random numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot generate a *really* random number in portable C99. But you could use some [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (and perhaps seed it with the current time).

And computers don't know about true real numbers. Only floating point. See http://floating-point-gui.de/

<sup>Actually I believe that the universe does not know about real numbers (think about some cardinality argument similar to [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)). But ask physicists or philosophers.</sup>

Some operating systems or implementations have PRNGs, and some systems (including) hardware have even genuine random generators.

Read about [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) & [drand48(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html) if your system has it. If on Linux, read also [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html)

You might try

```
double my_random_number /* between 0 & 0.5 */ = drand48() * 0.5;
```

to generate an almost uniformly distributed random number >= 0 and < 0.5

See also [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard header [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) if you accept to code in C++ ...

Comment: Actually, `/dev/random` on Unix-like boxes and `CryptGenRandom` on Windows boxes may very well get entropy from hardware-based random number generators available on many modern computers, and so may be truly random, not just algorithmically pseudo-random.

Comment: Didn't I mention that in my second paragraph. And `random(4)` tells about it.

Comment: I think he's using "real" in the mathematical sense; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number rather than "real" in the "truly" sense: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudo-random_numbers Good answer though.

Comment: A pseudo-random number uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 with time as seed, and multiplied by max value (0.5) solved. Yes, I used "real" in mathematical sense.