# Why is my random array & sort program not working?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, random, insertion-sort

I've tried looking up similar questions but I haven't seemed to find anything which solves my problem.

I need to write a program which generates an array of random numbers and sorts them via *insertion sort*. The actual randomness of the array isn't that important; the important thing is that the code itself generates them. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c) that  `rand() % n+1`  is sufficient for my needs to generate a number between 1 and `n`.

The code for my program is:

```c
/*
 * Task 1, question e
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Random Array Length
#define L 10
#define MAX 100

void naive_sort(int[]);

int main(){

    int i, a[L];

    //Generate an array of random numbers
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
        a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);

    //Unsorted Array
    printf("\nUnsorted array: ");
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            printf("%d    ", a[i]);

    //Sorted Array
    naive_sort(a);

    return 0;
}

void naive_sort(int a[]){
    int i, j, t;

    for(i=1; i < L; i++){
        t=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((t < a[j]) && (j >= 0)){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1]=t;
    }

    printf("\nSorted array: ");
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
        printf("%d    ", a[i]);
}
```

The algorithm just seems to be repeating some numbers and not sorting the list at all.

[image: Output]

Any help with the issue would be greatly appreciated, I've even tried [duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) but that doesn't seem to work either!

Comment: due to precedence of operators in C, this line: `rand() % n+1` will produce values in the range 0...n.  (x%y) will produce values in the range 0...(y-1) not (1...y) so this line: `a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);` is not correct. Suggest: `a[i]= (rand() % MAX) +1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my PC [kubuntu, g++] your code works.

Putting some print-statements in your program can help you.
The sorting routing-function you should call insert-sort.

Georg Fuss

Comment: Turns out my compiler had access rights problems and wasn't overwriting the old file. My code was fine after all.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning to `a[L]` instead of `a[i]`.

In the sorting loop you're assigning the same `t` to several `a[j+1]`, that can't be right. The original uses `a[j]` instead.

Switch the order of the two conditions of thebwhile loop. Current order invokes undefined behaviour by reading `a[-1]` before checking that `j` is still `>= 0`.

Comment: Goodness, don't I feel silly now! Another thing however - the sort isn't working either.

Comment: I've amended the post accordingly.

Comment: I based my program on [this](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/program-to-implement-insertion-sort-in-c-programming.html). I can't seem to spot the flaw when I cross check it with my function.

Comment: yeah I fixed that again. (sorry I keep doing that)