# Is this a good approach to random byte array genaration in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, random

I know this kind of question has been already discussed here: [How to generate a random number in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

But I wanted to share the way I implemented it just to know what people may think about it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

long int getNanoSecs(){
    struct timespec unixtimespec;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, &unixtimespec);
    return unixtimespec.tv_nsec;
}
```

.
.
.

```
unsigned char personal_final_token[PERSONAL_FINAL_TOKEN_SIZE_SIZE];
                unsigned char pwd_ptr_ctr;
                srandom(getNanoSecs()*(getNanoSecs()&0xFF));
                for(pwd_ptr_ctr=0;pwd_ptr_ctr<PERSONAL_FINAL_TOKEN_SIZE_SIZE;pwd_ptr_ctr++){
                    memset(personal_final_token+pwd_ptr_ctr,(random()^getNanoSecs())&0xFF,1);
                }
```

just define PERSONAL_FINAL_TOKEN_SIZE_SIZE and you can generate a quite random token of the size you want.

Comment: Maybe you should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's probably a poor approach.

Comment: Trying to make a random generator more random is quite counterproductive.

Comment: I don't see the point of xor-ing random() with getNanoSecs(). What's worse: you are taking the least significant bits of the random number (&0xFF). These are usually less random than the most significant bits.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, I would like to hear a technical objection to this method to generate an array of random number.
It involves simple bitwise  operations and it only reads nanosec from SO so it should be efficient and quite unpredictive. If you think it's not in this way please answer in a detailed way.

Comment: Xorig it's needed, let's say that each call to getNanoSecs() will generate maybe near or however increasing numbers, so it reduces the randomness, BUT xoring with a random value, whose first seed is getNanoSecs(), solves this problem. Thanx to Frank for the technical approach

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot please put back c++ flag, this solution is suitable for C++ too

Comment: @Whitefield: your title and description contradict. Update your question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanx for the clear and precise explanation.

Comment: XOR ing with nano seconds is a sure way to break any cryptographic properties the underlying random generator might have.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Can you be more explicit please ? I don't get in which sense you see a contradiction

Comment: it depends. If your PRNG is for some cryptographic code then no, it's a poor approach (very very likely). If this is for some game, not critical code then it could be fine. What about using rand() or mersenne twister or whatever pre-made? The fact is, independently on how much effort you put in it, it's gonna be a poor PRNG. That's why we have PRNGs out there ready to be used :-)

Comment: @Whitefield: you specifically only mention C.

Comment: @DanielJour really?! if you are able to tell me how I'll listen very carefully to your explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79344/is-it-possible-to-make-a-more-secure-random-number-generator-algorithm-by-xoring

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Hi, My goal is to generate a random byte array, the thing which it is really not clear to me is, how is it possibile to predict the number of nano sec that have passed??? you should consider a lot of uncertanty (so shchedule of different process, interrupts and so on). While  using only random() or rand() your randomness depends only on the seed I think this way is 'even more random' as there is noway to predict the value of getNanoSecs() exept for the fact that 2 near calls will probably produce two near values. But Xoring with random solves this problem for sure.

Comment: You say "for sure", but you're asking a lot of questions in response to others' comments, so I don't think you're so sure...

Comment: @Whitefield I see what you want to do. You could use /dev/rand which collects entropy from the machine behavior

Comment: @Whitefield It's more than likely that the clock source doesn't have actual nanosecond precision and your multiplication in `srandom` will always multiply by 0 on some systems and you'll have the exact same seed all the time. If you want numbers that are actually unpredictable you need to use a proper cryptographic PRNG. (I'm using the word "unpredictable" because the word "random" in programming tends to mean "perfectly predictable and repeatable").

Comment: @Whitefield You don't need to collect entropy along the way. If you manage to capture a very strong seed at startup and if you use a good PRNG you are pretty much done. How to get a really strong seed? cat /dev/rand

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thanks for the article, I'm reading it but the hypothesis are not matched in this case I think, I'm xoring them to solve a specific problem, not just to encrease the entropy. let me better explain, If I had to call just once getNanoSecs() it would be fine as random generator I think. But since I call it to generate a byte array, I need to call it more than once in a raw , there could be a problem. A simpler version could make use only of random & 0xFF seeded with getNanoSecs()

Comment: No, it's still totally unclear. What's the problem? What's wrong with just a plain `random()`?

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini thanks for your advice, it may be of interest http://askubuntu.com/questions/192203/how-to-use-dev-urandom too

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I just didn't like the idea of having an entire byte sequence depending on a single initial seed.

Comment: @FrankPuffer I don't agree with what you said please check the result of unsigned long long int test = 1000000001; printf("test %llu\n", test & 0xFF);

Comment: @Whitefield your PRNG *should* depend only on a initial value! If the PRNG is strong you actually don't have to feed the PRNG itself along the way

Comment: @Whitefield, I think your initial seed is the source of the problem here. An attacker who has a reasonable idea when you ran this will be able to find the correct seed quickly. https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/ddj-netscape.html. I would suggest focusing on seeding the PRNG well, and then you can reseed with time + PRNG output occasionally if you like. Tinkering with the PRNG algorithm itself is very likely to weaken it.

Comment: @tbroberg Hi, the number of nanoseconds is not a unix timestamp with nano seconds, on the contrary it varies from 0 to 10^9-1 every second of the internal clock of the machine so I think that it should be very difficult for an attacker knowing exactly this value.

Comment: @whitefield Recommend that you don't take for granted that the clock is sampled every time you call. I added an answer below so I could provide the code.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your clock source, or you may get unexpected results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/time.h>

#define SAMPLES 10

long getNanoSecs(){
  struct timespec unixtimespec;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, &unixtimespec);
  return unixtimespec.tv_nsec;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i;
  long clocks[SAMPLES];

  for (i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
    clocks[i] = getNanoSecs();
  for (i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
    printf("%lu\n", getNanoSecs());

  return 0;
}
```

[tbroberg@www src]$ ./a.out
727544983
728544969
728544969
728544969
728544969
728544969
728544969
728544969
728544969
728544969

Comment: You are right infacts I used CLOCK_REALTIME instead of CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE

Answer (score 0):

you are definitely right, I wanted to add that I modified `CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE` to `CLOCK_REALTIME`

as per linux man:

"CLOCK_REALTIME
System-wide  clock  that  measures real (i.e., wall-clock) time. Setting this clock requires appropriate privileges.  This  clock is  affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually changes the clock), and by the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3) and NTP.

CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE (since Linux 2.6.32; Linux-specific)
A  faster  but less precise version of CLOCK_REALTIME.  Use when you need very fast, but not fine-grained timestamps."

However thank you for YOUR_TIME :)