# Random number generator game in C

Tags: c

I have started C recently and am having trouble make the computer think of a random number.
This is the code so far. I need help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    time_t t;
    int userin;
    printf("Guess a number from 1 to 10\n");
    scanf("%d", userin);
    int r = rand() % 11;

    if (r == userin)
    {
        printf ("you are right");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Try again");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thx a lot guys it worked out!!!!

Comment: You don't call `srand` function. Include `time.h` and call `srand(time(NULL));` after variables declaration.

Comment: Missing `&` while reading: `scanf("%d", &userin);` instead of `scanf("%d", userin);`

Comment: Interesting that code generates the random number after user input.  Of course the order is not that important - it just seems like the code is cheating with knowing user input first.  Could simply code  `puts("Guess a number from 1 to 10"); scanf("*%s"); puts(rand()%10 == 0 ? "you are right" : "Try again");`  Is a compare to proper user input really needed? User win 1/10 of the time in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems :**

```
scanf("%d", userin); //you are sending variable
```

- This is not right as you need to send **address** of the `variable` as argument to the `scanf()` not the `variable`

so instead change it to :

```
scanf("%d", &userin); //ypu need to send the address instead
```

---

and `rand()%11` would produce any number from `0` to `10` but not from `1` to `10`

as other answer suggests, use :

```
(rand()%10)+1 //to produce number from 1 to 10
```

---

**Solution :**

And also include `time.h` function to use `srand(time(NULL));`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int userin;

    printf("Guess a number from 1 to 10\n");
    scanf("%d", &userin);
    int r = (rand() % 10)+1;

    if (r==userin)
    {
        printf ("you are right");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Try again");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

> **Why use `srand(time(NULL))` ?**
>
> - `rand()` isn't random at all, it's just a function which produces a sequence of numbers which are superficially random and repeat themselves over a period.
> - The only thing you can change is the seed, which changes your start position in the sequence.
>
> and, `srand(time(NULL))` is used for this very reason

Comment: Suggest re-wording "and rand()%11 would produce any number from 0 to 10 but not but not from 0 to 10"

Answer (score 5):

In your code, `r` will be a random number from 0 to 10. For a random number between 1 and 10, do this:

```
int r = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

Also, you should call

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

at the beginning of `main` to seed the random number generator. If you don't seed the generator, it always generates the same sequence.

Answer (score 2):

There is issue in your `scanf` statement as well.

You should use

```
scanf("%d", &userin);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d", userin); /* wrong - you need to use &userin */
```

`scanf` needs the address of variables at which it will store the value. For a variable, this is given by the prefexing the variable with `&`, as in `&userin`.

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues in your code.

1. not reading into the address `&` of your variable using `scanf`
2. not considering "legitimate" values of input, result of `rand()%11` can also be `0`
3. not checking against "illegal" input values, which can "alias" the result.
4. not properly initializing **seed** of the pseudo-random `rand()` function, so it always returns the same result.

Using `printf` for debugging your code, as in the following example, based on your code can help a lot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DEBG 1

int main (void)
{
    time_t t;
    int userin;
    printf("Guess a number from 1 to 10\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &userin) != 1){  // read into the variable's address
        printf("Conversion failure or EOF\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(userin < 1 || userin > 10){  // check against "illegal" input
        printf("Offscale, try again\n");
        return 1;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));              // initialize the seed value
    int r = 1 + rand() % 10;        // revise the formula

    if (DEBG) printf("%d\t%d\t", r, userin);  //debug print

    if (r==userin){
        printf ("you are right\n");
    }else{
        printf("Try again\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please, also consult [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @chux, really a good programming habit: one shouldn't ignore `scanf()` return value. (-:

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int main ()
  {
        int userIn = 0; //I like to initialize
        printf("Guess a number from 1 to 10\n");
        scanf("%d", &userIn);

        srand(time(NULL)); //seed your randum number with # of seconds since the Linux Epoch

        int r = (rand()%10)+1; //rand%11 gives values 0-10 not 1-10.  rand%10 gives 0-9, +1 makes sure it's 1-10

        if (r == userIn)
        {
        printf ("you are right\n");
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Try again\n");
        }
        return 0;
   }
```

Edit: You may want to implement code to verify that the user input is in fact an integer.