# Generating Random Numbers

Tags: c, random

Given a set of consecutive numbers S1 i.e [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...N1].Also a small set S2 of consecutive numbers i.e [1,2,3,4,5,6....N2]. N2<< N1

Now starting from first element i.e S2[i](i: 1 to N2) of set S2, you have to pick S2[i] consecutive **RANDOM** **numbers** from S1. Once you pick any number from S1,in any i(th) turn you can't pick it anymore in any other turn.

So my main goal is learn 'How To pick **RANDOM numbers** in such way'.This question is not part of any Coding Competition, or Homework. It is only for learning purpose.

If possible please use C language,as i am beginner in programming.

Comment: did you google for 'c random number' . I did. First hit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c

Comment: SO is meant for answering specific programming questions, not general ones. One clue that your question is off-topic is that you haven't even included any code. Please thoroughly read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) - in particular, ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please start with a program that generates random numbers. Then restrict the range to the indexed length of an array. Then step by tiny step ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asks us to do the poster's work for him.

Answer (score 1):

Use **rand()** function defined in C standard Library, and make an array of length in which you have to produce random number. Then on getting the particular number, simply put a value 1 in the particular array space. Again if you get same random number where the value is 1 in the array then start random function again so as to get a new random element.