# Is there anyway to generate character space(32) to ~(126) using sodium.h ? Or other way to generate secure string?

Tags: c, random, passwords, libsodium

I am creating a C program to generate passwords.

`rand()` in C keep generating some same set of strings even using `srand((unsigned int)**main + (unsigned int)&argc + (unsigned int)time(NULL))` found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c/32246689#32246689) but better than using `srand(time(NULL))`

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c/39475626#39475626), and I finally know how to link libsodium to my project.

After that, I realise I only can set the upper bound for `randombytes_uniform()`, the lower bound is always `0`.

And using `randombytes_random()` give me all kind of characters that cannot use in password.

Can anyone know how to generate character space(32) to character ~(126) using sodium or any secure way to generate character?

Here is the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sodium.h"
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

void main(int argc, char **argv){

    /* Length of the password */
    int length, num, temp, number;
    num = 10;
    length = 10;
    number = num;

    clear_screen();

    /* Seed number for rand() */
    srand((unsigned int)**generate_standard_password + (unsigned int)&argc + (unsigned int)time(0));

    while (num--)
    {
        temp = length;
        printf("\n\t%2d. ", (number - num));
        while (temp--) {
            putchar(rand() % 56 + 65);
            srand(rand());
        }
        temp = length;
    }
    printf("\n\n\t");
    system_pause();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 126 - 32 + 1 = 95 characters for you to choose from.  So mod the result of `rand` by 95, then add 32.  That will give you a number in the range you want.

The reason you keep getting the same set of characters is because you're reseeding after every call.  You should only seed *once* at startup,

```
while (temp--) {
    putchar((rand() % 95) + 32);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `r mod h` if `h` doesn't divide `max(r) + 1`, or else the output will be biased towards lower values.

The `rand()` function returns a value between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, which is typically `2^31`. So the output of `rand() % 95` is more likely to be `0`, `1` or `2` than other values.

This is the whole point of the `randombytes_uniform()` function in libsodium: to provide unbiased output for arbitrary ranges.

`randombytes_uniform(95)` returns a value between `0` and `94` (inclusive). Just add `32` if this is what you want: `32 + randombytes_uniform(95)`.