# How can you make a random number generator that chooses between the number 2 or 3. (not 1,2,3)

Tags: c, random

Hi I am working on a monty hall generator and in part of my code I need it to generate random number 2 or 3. It cannot be 1,2,3 but the computer needs to select between 2 or 3. 
Thanks!

I have tried  `randomCarDoor = ( rand() % 3 ) + 1;` but does not work.

`randomCarDoor = ( rand() % 3 ) + 1;`

It gives me the number `1,2,3` but I just want `2` and `3`

Comment: Maybe `rand() % 2 + 2`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random int in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c)

Comment: is it possible to do it with the number 1 and 3?

Comment: If you're not worried about *bias*, use (the number of wanted results) as the operand of `%`. In your case that's `2` for the results `2` and `3`. So `rand()%2` gives `0` or `1`; and when you add two you get `2` or `3`.

Comment: Random12 = ( rand() % 2 ) + 1; would this be how to set a random number from 1-2?

Comment: @ShopimoOnline Yes, `rand() % 2` will be either `0` or `1`, so the result will be `1` or `2`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That can suffer from a pathology in that linear congruential generators tend to draw odd -> even -> odd etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the low order bit of the random value, but it is very risky as some pseudo-random number generators do not provide adequate dispersion on low order bits:

```
int two_or_three = 2 + rand() % 2;
```

A much better way is to use the magnitude of the random number which is specified as having a flat distribution:

```
int two_or_three = 2 + (rand() >= RAND_MAX / 2);
```

If you want numbers `1` and `3`, here is a simple solution for any pair:

```
int random_value = (rand() < RAND_MAX / 2) ? 1 : 3;
```

Comment: Your first way is awful! (Oops!) but the second approach much better.

Comment: @Bathsheba: yes, I reworded the answer to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

As @Kerrek SB suggest, your formula is: random() % 2 + 2:

- random() % 2 ==> Gets [0 or 1]
- [0 or 1] + 2 ==> Gets [2 or 3]

A functional code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>



int main()
{
    // Declare variables
    int i;
    int randomNumber;

    // Set random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Get 10 random numbers between 2 and 3
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        randomNumber = rand() % 2 + 2;
        printf("Random %d: %d\n", i, randomNumber);
    }

    // End function
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not trivial using `rand()` since a linear congruential generator typically alternates between odd and even numbers.

So one of the *worst* things you can do it to use a formula based on `rand() % 2`.

In this *particular* case, I suggest you draw based on

```
n = rand();
```

and call it `1` if `n < RAND_MAX / 2` and `3` otherwise, which you can do with

```
rand() < RAND_MAX / 2 ? 1 : 3
```

That might have adequate statistical properties - perhaps some unwanted autocorrelation - but probably no worse than `rand()` itself.