# rand() function behavior

Tags: c, random

I'm learning about the `rand()` function in C, as I want to use it to generate a random number in a range. However, I have a question about a part of the algorithm below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    const MAX = 20, MIN = 1;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randNumber = rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
    printf("%d", randNumber);
    // yeu cau nhap so
    int duDoan;
    printf("Moi ban du doan con so:");
    scanf("%d", &duDoan);
    // chay vong lap kiem tra
    while(duDoan != randNumber) {
        printf("Ban da sai. Moi nhap lai:");
        scanf("%d", &duDoan);
    }
    printf("Ban da nhap dung. Dap an la: %d ", randNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

What confuses me here is why we have to add `+ MIN` in this line:

```
rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
```

If I leave it, what will the result be?

Comment: Surely you can run the code and experiment with it. If rand() % 50 gives you a number between 0 and 49, what would you do if you wanted a number between 30 and 79?

Comment: The subtraction tells you how many numbers are needed in the range 0.. and when you add the random number to `MIN` then *voilà* you have a number in the desired range.

Comment: What does `rand ()% (MAX - MIN + 1)` deliver, and what do you have to do with it to get a number inclusive to the range `[MIN...MAX]` ?

Comment: As a side note, Stack Overflow is an English site. Translating the variable names and strings in the code would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c

Comment: Note this has little to do with the behaviour of `rand()` and everything to do with the semantics of the `%` operator.

Comment: @JL2210 : I think we can manage.   Asking for a rewrite of the code in question is somewhat unreasonable and will possibly introduce errors not in the original code or relevant to the question.   I'd rather the code posted was the exact code the question referred to.   In this case the part of the code in question _is_ in English in any case.

Comment: OK. If anybody's curious as to what language this is (so they can translate it and understand the code better), it's Vietnamese.

Comment: Sorry everyone this is my first time in this forum. I hope everyone will give up on the language problem, I will fix it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand()` is a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`.

`rand() % n` is a number between 0 and n - 1.  If you want a value from 0 to n, then you need `rand() % (n+1)`.

In your example `(MAX - MIN + 1)` is the *span* of integer values to generate, while `MIN` is the lower value. So for example where:

```
MIN = -10
MAX = 10
```

the *span* `n` :

```
n = (MAX - MIN + 1) = 21
```

so that:

```
rand() % n
```

yields values from 0 to 20, and

```
rand() % n - MIN
```

is -10 to +10.  Without the +1, it would incorrectly be -10 to +9.

Note that where a statistically high quality random number is required restricting the span by the use of `%` is flawed and will introduce a bias when `n` is not a factor of `RAND_MAX + 1`. In that case `(int)(n * ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX))` is a better solution, so you would have:

```
int randNumber = (int)((MAX - MIN) * ((double)rand() /
                                      (double)RAND_MAX)) + MIN ;
```

Note there is no +1 here because the range of `(double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX` is 0 to 1, so multiplying by n gives 0 to n *inclusive*.