# How to generate random seed for random numbers

Tags: c, public-key-encryption, private-key, gmp, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to generate big random numbers for the public key and private key. I have problem with the initial seed to generate a random 256-bit private key on client-side.
as you may know, we shouldn't use `rand` or `srand` function in C because it's easy to break.
how can I generate a random seed to generate a random 256-bit private key?
I use GMP's Linear congruential Algorithm to generate random number in C.

Comment: [This is probably what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c/39475626#39475626)

Comment: Re “I use GMP's Linear congruential Algorithm to generate random number in C”: Are you saying you want to use a high-quality truly random source for the seed and then you will use a simple linear congruential algorithm to generate numbers from it? That is not a good idea.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for comment. what's your suggestion for a high-quality random number? which algorithm should I use?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a crypto library for this? It should use the best available source of randomness to generate its keys.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for comment. which library you suggest? the only good library i know is openssl.

Comment: I've never written any crypto code, so I can't recommend anything specific.

Comment: You could use for example [HMAC-DRBG](https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/api_ref/rng.html#hmac-drbg). For seeding, you would use either `/dev/random` / `/dev/urandom` as suggested in the answer or a hardware-based RNG source (depending on what you have available, e.g. from a TPM, a PKCS#11 smartcard or a processor-specific provider).

Comment: Have you read the [gmp docs](https://gmplib.org/gmp-man-6.0.0a.pdf)? Check section 9.2. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On unix systems, you can read from `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` files to get some "randomness" byte sequences. Those sequences are based on your system entropy.
See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom) post for more details about their differences.

```
#include <unistd.h> // read
#include <fcntl.h>  // open
#include <stdio.h>  // printf

int main(void)
{
    int             fd;
    unsigned int    seed;

    fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);

    read(fd, &seed, sizeof seed);

    printf("%u\n", seed);

    //  Then you can use srand with your new random seed

    return (0);
}
```

Note: Don't forget to check for errors after open and read, and to close `fd` after use.