# Generate random multiple numbers in c

Tags: c, random

I'm working on my school project and having an issue generating random numbers that are multiples of some other numbers(for example generating randoms that are multiples of 25)
Can someone please help me with the codes?(C language)

Comment: generate random numbers then multiply them by 25. Use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c

Comment: You may want to read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random int in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Simply generate a random int between 1 and a max multiply-by number, and multiply this with your number (25 in your example)
code-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MULT_NUM 25

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % 20 + 1;
    printf("The random multiple of %d is: %d\n", MULT_NUM, r * MULT_NUM);

    return 0;
}
```