# When I run my program I get the 'Segmentation fault 11' error. I'm not sure what in my code would cause this error

Tags: c, memory-management

I understand that this error has to do with how much memory my program tries to use when I run it, but I'm new to C and I don't quite have a handle on memory management yet. If anyone wants to take the time to tell me where in my code this is occurring I would very much appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char * getRandomHex(int length, char * result) {
    char hexCharacters[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char randChar = hexCharacters[rand()%16];
        strncat(result, &randChar, 1);
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char * result;
        result = getRandomHex(6, result);
        printf("%s", result);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `strncat` function concatenates *strings*.  But `randChar` is a single character, not a string.

Comment: You will also need to properly null-terminate your `result` string after constructing it.

Comment: Also, in your `main` function, you need to somehow allocate memory for your `result` pointer to point to.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will try implementing those things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 3 of these are the main issues:

1. `main()`: allocate space for result.
2. `getRandomHex()` assign to `result[i]` instead of using `strncat()` incorrectly.
3. `getRandomHex()`: don't assume that `result` argument contains a terminating '\0'.
4. `getRandomHex()` using a string as it's easier to write.   Making it `static const` as it read-only.
5. Removed unused headers.
6. Define `LEN` instead of the magic number 6.
7. Derived size of `hexCharacters()` instead of hard-coding it to `16`.
8. Combine the two print statements, and using the return value (which is the `result` variable).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 6

// caller must allocate result array of size at least length + 1 bytes
char *getRandomHex(int length, char *result) {
    static const char hexCharacters[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = hexCharacters[rand() % (sizeof(hexCharacters) - 1)];
    }
    result[length] = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main() {
    char result[LEN + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", getRandomHex(LEN, result));
    }
}
```

Comment: You will *probably* want to seed your pRNG, unless the deterministic nature of the current output is desired (see: [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand)). The cursory `<time.h>` was likely included as a preamble to the [usual simplistic way of creating a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822368/2505965).

Comment: @Oka good comment, thanks.  It is not clear if op wants the current or proposed changed behavior.