# Calling random number generator ran2() available in Numerical recipes in c

Tags: c, random

I am using `ran2()` function in c programming codes. `ran2()` is known as more truly random number generator. I found that `ran2()` is also generates numbers in same sequence. Why is it so?

`ran2` takes a long type pointer variable.

The code of `ran2()` is available in Numerical recipes.

Here I'm writing how I called the function:

```
float temp;
long *seed,seed1;
seed=&seed1;
temp=ran2(seed);
```

After calling this function multiple times and running multiple times I see that numbers of same sequence are generated every time. Correct me where I am doing the mistake and what modifications needed to get the truly random sequence every time.

Comment: What is `ran2`? Please [edit] and clarify. OT: that being said, just write `temp=ran2(&seed1);` and drop `*seed,` and the whole line `seed=&seed1;`.

Comment: The code of ran2() is there in "Numerical recipes in c " It is the standard random number generator scientific community use .   Using ran2(&seed1) gives error as "segmentation fault (core dumped)".the function ran2 takes  long pointer variable as parameter.

Comment: Your comment rises another question: what is "Numerical recipes in C"? Please [edit]

Comment: Most likely, you are supposed to provide a seed value to `ran2()` — you get to choose which value to start with.  If you use `long seed = 1;` and then call `float temp = ran2(&seed);` repeatedly, you will get one sequence of numbers.  Change `1` to `2` and you'll get a different sequence, and so on.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve] along with the output you get.

Comment: The second edition of [Numerical Recipes in C](https://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Recipes-Scientific-Computing-Second/dp/0521431085/) is an old (1992) but fairly reliable textbook — but the licensing terms on the code in the book are draconian, IIRC.  I decided never to use it because of that.  (There is also a rather expensive [3rd Edition](https://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Recipes-3rd-Scientific-Computing-dp-0521880688/dp/0521880688/).)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan .Can you tell me how to get different sequence everytime ? There is a technique by using time function  available in time.h library.Can u tell me how to use this in my case .

Comment: It's a poor quality way of doing it, but `long seed = time(0);` will use the time as a seed value.  For a discussion of other ways to generate random seeds, see [Random password generator algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75946155/15168)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `ran2` requires `seed` to be negative to initialize. Otherwise it treats it as continuing state. `time(0)` is unlikely to provide that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: As I said, I've not looked at the book — the OP has the book and can find that sort of detail out for themselves by careful reading.

Comment: *`ran2()` is known as more truly random number generator* More "truly random" than what? [From 1994](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/cip/article/8/1/117/509983/Some-portable-very-long-period-random-number): "It is found that a proposed random number generator ran2, recently presented in the Numerical Recipes column [W. H. Press and S. A. Teukolsky, Comput. Phys. 6, 521–524 (1992)], is a good one, but a number of generators are presented that are at least as good and are simpler, much faster, and with periods ‘‘billions and billions’’ of times longer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for `ran2` in *Numerical Recipes* says “Call with `idum` a negative integer to initialize”. The parameter of `ran2` is `long *idum`. So, to use `ran2`, define a `long`, set it to a negative value, and pass a pointer to it to `ran2`. In non-sensitive uses, it is not uncommon to use the standard C `time` function to get a value to use to initialize random number generation. You will need to ensure it is negative. So you can use:

```
long seed = time(0);
if (0 <= seed)
    seed = -1 - seed;
…
float x;
…
x = ran2(&seed);
```

Answer (score 1):

The state of the art of pseudorandom number generation has advanced considerably since *Numerical Recipes* was published 30 years ago.  I don't know how `ran2` works but I can practically guarantee there are better choices nowadays.

Unless you are trying to reproduce results from an old piece of research that specifically used `ran2`, I strongly recommend you do not use it.  Instead, your first choice should be the keystream from a current-generation stream cipher, e.g. [ChaCha20](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html).  In the very unlikely event that that isn't fast enough for your application, [MELG-64](https://github.com/sharase/melg-64) is probably what I would try second.

Comment: Even immediately on publication, there were responses [like this](https://www.uwyo.edu/buerkle/misc/wnotnr.html):  "The NR-recommended random number generators RAN1 and RAN2 should not be used for any serious application. If you use the top bit of RAN1 to create a discrete random walk (plus or minus 1 with equal probability) of length 10,000, the variance will be around 1500, far below the desired value of 10,000." and

Comment: (cont)  "Both are low-modulus generators with a shuffling buffer, in one case with the bottom bits twiddled with another low-modulus generator. The moduli are just too low for serious work, and the resulting generators even out too well"

Comment: Thanks for the information .I will surely look on it .