# random value is same in each instance in loop

Tags: c

i want to generate a random value in each instance but its same please help here is my code i have used the header code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c) , each time the loop is being used i want to generate a new random value

here is my code

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "./random.h"

#define numberOfLoops 4
void main()
{
    const char *messages[] = {
        "Hello!",
        "How?",
        "Good!"};
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++)
    {
        int random_value = random_number(0, sizeof(messages) / sizeof(messages[0]) - 1);
        printf("\n%d", random_value);
        printf("\n%s", messages[random_value]);
    }
}
```

**random.h**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<time.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int random_number(int min_num, int max_num);

    int random_number(int min_num, int max_num)
    {
        int result = 0, low_num = 0, hi_num = 0;

        if (min_num < max_num)
        {
            low_num = min_num;
            hi_num = max_num + 1; // include max_num in output
        } else {
            low_num = max_num + 1; // include max_num in output
            hi_num = min_num;
        }

        srand(time(NULL));
        result = (rand() % (hi_num - low_num)) + low_num;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `srand()` every time before `rand()`?

Comment: Move srand() out of the function and place it at the beginning of main().