# Getting a byte of randomness

Tags: c++, memory, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most random function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822182/what-is-the-most-random-function-in-c)

In C++, is this safe:

```
int main() {
srand(time(0));
unsigned char arr[10];
for(int i=0; i <sizeof(arr); ++i)
    arr[i] = (unsigned char)rand();
}
```

Is there a better way to randomly fill a byte array in a platform independent way? failing that, is there a better way to do this on windows? (I know rand() isn't a very good PRNG, I'm just using it as an example).

Thank you!

Comment: 1) How do you define "safe"? 2) If not rand(), then what?

Comment: vocaro: 1) No UB. 2) That was my question ;).

Comment: you can also take a look at the generators from C++0x http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15319/

Comment: [According to Julienne Walker](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) (chapter “Seeing rand()”), this is UB.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I think he's got the conversion backwards. It's UB to convert random values _to_ `time_t`. But `time_t` is an arithmetic type, and converting them to an unsigned integral type is safe. You have roughly three potential issues: overflow, underflow, and loss of precision. Overflow is not UB because assigning a value to an unsigned integral types is done modulo 2^N. Underflow and loss of precision (rounding) are well-defined and just result in a lack of randomness.

Comment: @MSalters I’m pretty sure *Julienne* is a gal, even though she’s The Dude. To her defense, she doesn’t say it’s UB, merely that it theoretically doesn’t work without problems (though in practice it does). Perhaps I misconstrued that.

Answer (score 3):

What about using [boost.random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random.html)? The generators it uses can be passed to `std::generate` to fill your array, it's platform independent and headers-only. I would give a code sample but have no boost install available at the moment.

Edit: as mentioned: in C++0x (the upcoming standard), you can use tr1::random, which is essentially just the boost library becoming part of the standard C++ library.